# Alternatives to Assert

Tags: java, junit, assert, assertions

The reasons I am dissatisfied with *assert* keyword in Java are

1) it's disabled by default, so it is a headache to make sure it's enabled when I want it to be

2) its behavior is rather rigid (I would want some inversion of control, ideally); but that's not terribly important.

Some of the alternatives I can think about:

1. JUnit's *assertEquals()* and such - good for tests, but can't use in main code
2. Guava's preconditions - great, but no assertion methods per se.
3. My own assertion library - I wrote it back in 1999, and back at the time it was great, but now I want to standardize.
4. Anything else?

So.. to sum it up.. how do I assert in production code in a way that is not disabled by default?

(And yes, this may be considered an anti-pattern by some, but I do want at least some assertions in Production, even if assertion failures are just silently logged. I see some room for that even in shrink-wraps, and definitely in websites).

Comment: Have you tried [reflections asserter](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/reflectionassert/ReflectionAssert.html) ?

Comment: @StackFlowed Just looked up reflections asserter - neat! But what if I just want a simple fail() or assert(boolean)? Also - how fast are reflections these days? I remember them being very slow, but this must have changed.

Comment: Also - I really like Scala-style "should"-assertions, as opposed to "assert". Any library that does this?

Comment: I don't know about the performance. If you need something simple then I don't think performance should matter.

Comment: If this question is taken out of hold, (which I sure hope it does,) I will turn this into an answer: `if( development && !DebugHelpers.isAssertEnabled() ) throw new RuntimeException( "assertions are not enabled. When 'development' is defined, please make sure to run with -enableassertions (-ea for short.)" );`

Comment: @MikeNakis Thank you for your answer. I am aware of this, but it is certainly nice to mention. What is this DebugHelpers? Is it an Android thing?

Comment: No, it is nothing, just a class that I, you, anyone, could have written to hold globally visible debugging-related stuff.

Comment: I just write my own class.  It only needs to be a few lines long to reliably provide the same functionality as Java's `assert` command.  A slightly more sophisticated class that uses assertion objects can be found at http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/monitors/monitors.html .

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Spring's [Assert](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html) class, it includes a fairly extensive range of checks.

Comment: Interesting! Can it be used separately from the rest of Spring, and how much would it increase my footprint?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but I'm routinely using `commons-lang` [`Validate`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html) for many years already. Usually in public API methods/constructors to ensure that arguments are passed correctly. Not just `notNull` (see Lombok's [`@NotNull`](http://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html) for this) but also `noNullElements` etc.

I especially like the `<T> T notNull(T object)` signature for immutables:

```
private final JSCodeModel codeModel;
private final String name;

public FunctionDeclarationImpl(JSCodeModel codeModel, String name,
        String[] parameterNames, JSSourceElement[] sourceElements) {
    this.codeModel = Validate.notNull(codeModel);
    this.name = Validate.notNull(name);
    ...
}
```

What are your requirements, actually?

Comment: Not exactly what I want (but perhaps it is because, like you said, I did not make myself clear), but definitely good for general education, thank you! I want Inversion of Control, really! Like Log4j can log pretty much anywhere, I want my exception handler to do pretty much anything, whatever functionality I supply: pop a debugger (Eclipse), pop a window, write to a log file, send a message over a network, allow for remote debugger to connect, result in an error page.

Comment: Anyway, that's what my old framework does; but like I said, I want to standardize

Comment: @ТаняТ. This is a *very* different question. We have a custom solution for this (overlay on Log4j with direct and AOP-based integration and UDP-based transfer towards Icinga monitoring and many more). A proprietary solution, but an internal standard. (I'm work for a huge company.)

Comment: sounds like your company's solution is similar to mine. I never got around to doing AOP though it's been on my list for a long time (mine predates AOP), so mine just caught all exceptions and sent them to exception handler implementing IoC; ditto with assertions. It is hard to sell to new employers/clients though. If you don't mind my asking, what does your standard API looks like, on an interface level? P.S. Good to see a fellow compatriot.

Comment: @ТаняТ. I don't think it is similar. On the (Java) API level we have "unstructured" and "structured" situations. Unstructured are very similar to Log4j logging APIs. Structured situations are pre-defined (per application) in a "situation catalog" and we generate APIs like `MyAppCatalog.someProblem(P1 parameter1, P2 parameter2)`. AOP is different but I'm not using it in my projects and can't tell much. This is a huge topic.

Comment: Correction. Mine caught all exceptions that are bugs and sent them to error handler. Some exceptions of course were processed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

> JUnit's assertEquals() and such - good for tests, but can't use in main code

Nothing technically prevents you from using JUnit assetions (and/or Hamcrest matchers) in your main code. Just include the Junit jar in your classpath. It's usually not done but that's more of a convention than any technical limitation.

Java 7 also introduced `Objects.requireNotNull(obj, message)` and similar methods although not as full featured as JUnit assertions.

but I think if you want to go with a more standardized approach Guava's preconditions is probably best.

Comment: I know it's a convention, but it's a major convention. To put unit testing in production just for an assert statement seems an overkill, considering the alternatives.